# How does collections.Iterable work with isinstance()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, collections, iterable

I was wondering why the `isinstance` function works with `collections.Iterable` for checking whether the object is iterable, if it isn't a subclass of `Iterable`.

If we have two classes:

```
class first_class(object):
    pass

class second_class(object):
     def __iter__(self):
         pass
```

Calling `ininstance(first_class(), Iterable)` returns `False`.

Calling `isinstance(second_class(), Iterable)` returns `True`.

The documentation of `isinstance` says: "Return whether an object is an instance of class or of a subclass thereof".

Because both classes are subclasses of `object`, why would one return that it is a subclass of `Iterable` and the other isn't?

I get that it is because of the `__iter__` method, but I don't understand why it affects `isinstance`'s result, if the inheritance is the same in both classes.

I got more confused when I tried the following:

```
x = first_class()
x.__iter__ = lambda: None
```

If the addition of the `__iter__` method made second_class iterable, why after the above code, which added an `__iter__` method, `isinstance(x, Iterable)` still return `False`?

Comment: I don't have time to write a proper answer (apologies), but ABCs implement the [`__subclasshook__` ](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.__subclasshook__) method which checks the type for the relevant methods/attributes (e.g. [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_collections_abc.py#L243-L256)). As for the dynamically adding `__iter__` to the first class - it won't work because the attribute is looked up on the object's class, not the object itself.